# Frequency of digits in my 2-D array not outputting correctly

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My goal is if for example I would make the size of my array 2x6 and I would input values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) for row 1 and values (0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9) for row 2 it would output:
Digit 0 occurs 2 times
Digit 1 occurs 2 times
Digit 2 occurs 1 times
etc.
but it doesn't.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int row, col, N, M, count, row1, col1;

 printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array.\n");
 printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");
 scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

 int digits[N][M], freq[N][M];

 for (row = 0; row < N; row++){ 
  printf("Enter row %d: ", row);
  for (col = 0; col < M; col++){
   scanf("%d", &digits[row][col]);
  }
 } 

 freq[row][col] = -1;

 for (row = 0; row < N; row++){
  count = 1;
  for (row1 = row + 1; row1 < N; row1++){
   for (col = 0; col < M; col++){
    for (col1 = col + 1; col1 < M; col1++){
     if (digits[row][col] == digits[row1][col1]){
      count++;
      freq[row1][col1] = 0;
     }
    }
    if (freq[row][col] != 0){
     freq[row][col] = count;
    }
   } 
  } 
 }

 printf("Total counts for each digit:\n");
 for (row = 0; row < N; row++){
  for (col = 0; col < M; col++){
   if (freq[row][col] != 0){
    printf("Digit %d occurs %d times\n", digits[row][col], freq[row][col]);
   }
  } 
 } 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5" will not work with `scanf("%d"...` given those commas.  Post _exact_ example input.

Comment: `freq[row][col] = -1;` is UB as that is outside `freq`.  What is that code for?

Comment: `freq[N][M]` is not initialized.  Some elements are assigned later - certainly a problem when totalizing.  Code is not clear as to its goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second loop is not counting what you expect, why don't you try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int row, col, digit, N, M, currentValue;

 printf("This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array.\n");
 printf("Enter the size of the array (Row Column): ");
 scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

 int digits[N][M], freq[10] = { 0 };

 for (row = 0; row < N; row++){ 
  printf("Enter row %d: ", row);
  for (col = 0; col < M; col++){
   scanf("%d", &currentValue);
   digits[row][col] = currentValue;
   if (currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <=9) {
     freq[currentValue]++;
   }
  }
 } 

 printf("Total counts for each digit:\n");
 for (digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++){
   if (freq[digit] != 0){
    printf("Digit %d occurs %d times\n", digit, freq[digit]);
   }
 } 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works now, but I don't understand why you set digits[row][col] = currentvalue, why the array freq is only 1-D, and why you used row for freq[row]. Would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: Sure. currentValue is a temporal variable that will store user input is just for doing the code more verbose, you can remove it but then we will have freq[digits[row][col]]++; that looks hard to read.

Comment: And about freq 1-D array is because it will need to have the frequency of numbers from 0-9 so if it's an array of 10 positions which index starts in 0 we can say each position represents one digit. When the users enter 0, we increase freq[0] by one.  The second cycle just reutilize row, but you can use a new variable like digit instead. What the second cycle does is iterating through freq from 0-9 (position and digit) and printing the value of each one.